# Operation along the same column given a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of amounts I want to add up for a particular currency code and display that total along with the underlying currency.

SOURCE TABLE TRANS

| PORTCODE | AMOUNT | CCYTYPE | CCYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BC100 | 40 | DAC | DAC |
| BC100 | 30 | DAC | DAC |
| BC100 | 30 | DAC | DAC |
| BC100 | 35 | ROPE | EUR |
| BC100 | 25 | ROPE | EUR |
| BC100 | 25 | ROPE | EUR |

For example:

```
Select CCYCODE
FROM TRANS  
WHEN CCYTYPE='ROPE'
```

```
    OUTPUT
    EUR
```

However, I am also using the CCYTYPE='DAC' to perform a calculation such as:

```
    SELECT 
    T.PORTCODE, 
    T.ID, 
    T.VAN = sum(amount)
    FROM TRANS T
    INNER JOIN METRIC M 
    ON T.METRICCODE=M.METRICCODE
    WHERE 1=1
    AND T.CCYTYPE='DAC'
```

The sum is comprised of several hundred amounts in the TRANS table.

```
OUTPUT
PORTCODE | ID     | VAN     | CCYCODE
BC100    | 31     | 100     | EUR
```

How can I get the result of the ccytype, portcode, ID, and VAN to appear together with these two distinct conditions?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the two individual queries is incorrect. But assuming it is correct, you can put each individual query in a subquery and join it like it were a table.

Assuming what is common between query 1 and query 2 is `PORTCODE` you can do the following:

```
SELECT
    a.* 
    ,b.CCYCODE
FROM 
(SELECT 
        T.PORTCODE, 
        T.ID, 
        sum(amount) AS VAN
    FROM TRANS T
    INNER JOIN METRIC M 
    ON T.METRICCODE=M.METRICCODE
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND T.CCYTYPE='DAC' 
GROUP BY 
    T.PORTCODE, 
    T.ID
) AS a
LEFT JOIN 
(Select 
        PORTCODE
        ,CCYCODE
     FROM TRANS  
    WHEN CCYTYPE='ROPE'
) AS b
ON a.PORTCODE = b.PORTCODE
```